# Is there any python edit control can be embed in my c++ program?

Tags: c++, python, editor, controls

I am looking for a python edit control for my domain program, which is written in C++. It could be a C++ class or an ActiveX control.
Thanks.

Comment: what is a "domain program" ?

Comment: If you actually want to put a python script snippet in your c++ code that's possible with steps available here:  http://docs.python.org/2/extending/.  Otherwise, please provide (non)-working code that we can help you with, not just vague conceptual requests.

Comment: I want to show a text editor in my program. It support syntax coloring and indenting for python language. I know it simple to embed python vm in my program, but it seems no editor control I can use.

Comment: I know UliPad, PyPE, Anjuta and DrPython and so on, but they are all standlone program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Scintilla](http://www.scintilla.org/) is an obvious and common choice. It has a permissive license and is designed as a source code editor. It's written in C++ and the Windows version is a standard Win32 control based on Windows messages.

Comment: It seems that it is writted in GTK+. Can it be integrated with programs writted in MFC?

Comment: It's not written in GTK+. Read the documentation at the link I gave. There's a pure Win32 based example there. All the docs describe using it with good ole fashioned Windows messages.

Comment: I have download and buid it. Yes, It is a pure win32 dll. Thank you very much, this is very helpful to me!